# Error updating mongoDB Via Api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making an API which updates a MongoDB field via a query in the API (node). When I call upon findByIdAndUpdate it gives me the following error:

```
{"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ ':id': undefined }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"recipe\"",
"name": "CastError",
"stringValue": "\"{ ':id': undefined }\"",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": {},
"path": "_id"}
```

The query I am running:

```
routes.put('/recipes/:id', function(req, res) {
res.contentType('application/json');
Recipe.findByIdAndUpdate({':id': req.query._id}, {name: req.params.name, description : req.body.description, imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl})
.catch((error) => res.status(401).json(error)); });
```

The Recipe model:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    ingredients: []
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


const Recipe = mongoose.model('recipe', RecipeSchema);

const recipe = new Recipe({
    name: 'Tasty Schnitzel',
    description: 'A super-tasty Schnitzel - just awesome!',
    imageUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Schnitzel.JPG'
}).save();

module.exports = Recipe;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `req.params._id` is `undefined`, as the error states.

Comment: @Svenskunganka That is 'query' in my code, not 'params', a typo. The error remains.

Comment: If you `console.log(req.query._id)`, what do you get? Mongoose can't cast the *value* `undefined` to `ObjectId`.